# Are IMAP/SMTP credentials always the same as the user's login credentials?

Tags: email, smtp, imap, basic-authentication

#### Greetings!

This question pertains to `Normal` (or `Plain`) IMAP/SMTP Authentication.

Can we be sure that a user's IMAP username is exactly the same as his full email address? Can the two be different? What about his SMTP username? Can he have different passwords for IMAP and SMTP?

To make things concrete, consider a webmail user, John Doe:

- Email address: `john.doe@example.com`
- Login password: `foo.bar.baz`

Given that John uses the above credentials to sign in with his webmail provider, here's a series of yes–no questions:

1. Can we be **certain** that John's IMAP username is `john.doe@example.com`?

   - 1.1. Could it be `john.doe`, `john` or something else?
2. Can we be **certain** that John's IMAP password is `foo.bar.baz`?
3. Can we be **certain** that John's SMTP username is `john.doe@example.com`?
4. Can we be **certain** that John's SMTP password is `foo.bar.baz`?
5. Can we be **certain** that John's IMAP password is the same as his SMTP password?
6. Can we be **certain** that John's IMAP username is the same as his SMTP username?

I've been looking for these answers for a while now. If you can link to an RFC, that'd be awesome.

#### Thanks in advance. `:)`

Comment: All answers are "no" and won't be covered by an rfc.  Authentication is local policy, and can be based on anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMTP and IMAP can be handled by disjoint programs, so no assurances there. Dovecot IMAP for example lets you freely choose to map username against mailbox name.

Answer (score 1):

Certain - no, you can't be certain, as the server administrator can set any policy they like regarding these things.

However, [RFC 6186](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6186) gives some suggestions.  It suggests that mail user agents (MUAs) should first try using the full email address as the username for authentication (in this case `john.doe@example.com`), and if authentication fails, try again with the "local-part" as username (in this case `john.doe`).  It also suggests that service providers should support authenticating with either of those usernames.  This applies to both SMTP and IMAP authentication.

The RFC doesn't say anything about whether the username should be the same for SMTP and IMAP (so if the IMAP server wants the username `john.doe@example.com` and the SMTP server wants `john.doe`, that would still be within what the RFC suggests), and it doesn't say anything at all about passwords.

---

The RFC also suggests using DNS SRV records to find the hostname of the IMAP and SMTP servers given an email address.  You can see this in action for Gmail using the `dig` command line tool:

```
$ dig +short -t srv _imaps._tcp.gmail.com
5 0 993 imap.gmail.com.
$ dig +short -t srv _submission._tcp.gmail.com
5 0 587 smtp.gmail.com.
```

That is, the IMAPS server is on `imap.gmail.com`, port 993, and the SMTP server for mail submission is on `smtp.gmail.com`, port 587.